# select ONLY repeated rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to find users that received bonus at my DB. The only users that interest to me, are those who got bonus more than one time.

How should I work this query to get ONLY users who got bonus more than once?

```
select Bonus, BonusUser, BonusType, Amount 
from Bonus 
where BonusType="1" 
order by BonusUser asc;
```

I need a query that prompts all "duplicated" rows, so I can remove bonus from them.

I haven't explained before, but some users exploited a bug and could get free bonus, so I must select those duplicated rows, analyze and remove if it's abuse case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT Bonus
    , BonusUser
    , BonusType
    , Ammount 
FROM Bonus 
WHERE BonusType="1" 
GROUP BY BonusUser
HAVING Count(*) > 1
ORDER BY BonusUser asc;
```

Based on your comment, I think this is what you want, this will give you the list of all users with a bonus but it will give you the count of those who had more than one bonus:

```
SELECT Bonus
    , t.BonusUser
    , BonusType
    , amount 
    , t2.cntbonus
FROM Bonus t
inner join 
(
    select count(*) as CntBonus, bonususer
    from Bonus
    where BonusType='1'
    group by bonususer
) t2
    on t.bonususer = t2.bonususer
WHERE BonusType='1'
ORDER BY BonusUser asc
```

Comment: Its good, but it only tells me which users has more than one bonus.
I need also prompted all "duplicated" rows, so I can remove bonus from them.
I haven't explained before, but some users exploited a bug and could get free bonus, so I must select those duplicated rows, analyze and remove if it's abuse case.

Comment: so you want the list of all users with more than one bonus and those who got the bonus?

Comment: I want only a list of all characters that got the bonus atleast twice.
But I need it prompted like this:

BonusType BonusUser  Ammount Bonus
1          BlueFeet     2
1          BlueFeet     7
1          BlueFeet     4

Like this

Comment: can you edit your OP and post some sample data? as well as the expected results?

Comment: Good trick bluefeet, it's fixed now and what a statement hehehe. - THANK YOU

Answer (score 3):

you can do like below

```
   select BonusUser,
          count(*)
   from Bonus 
  where BonusType="1" 
  group by BonusUser
   having count(*)>1
  order by BonusUser asc
```

you must provide some dummy data with expected result ..

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the other answers, you can also do the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b1.*
FROM Bonus b1
JOIN Bonus b2
  ON b1.BonusUser = b2.BonusUser
  AND b1.Id > b2.Id
WHERE b1.BonusType = "1"
  AND b2.BonusType = "1"
ORDER BY b1.BonusUser ASC;
```